# Where are the steps needed (with appropriate and current links) to register a desktop SDK application for use with Quickbooks Online (QBOE)

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have a desktop SDK application that currently talks to the Desktop versions of QB.  I would like to add QBOE access (taking full account of the differences between the two).

I have not found out how to register an application and the links in the SDK PDF file take me to the wrong site or I get 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I found this below when I went here: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/

markdnielson 2 months ago 
 
To create a QBOE app, you will need to go to https://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/QBOE